# The automorphism group of the countable atomless Boolean algebra does not have ample generics

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory, automorphism-group

I was told that the automorphism group of the countable atomless Boolean algebra does not have ample generics.  I assume that one would show this by using the Fraisse-theoretic characterizations of countable ultrahomogeneous structures with automorphism groups with ample generics by means of finite structures expanded with $n$ partial automorphisms for $n < \omega$.  However, I have not been able to find any reference for this fact.  What would be a good reference?  I would also be grateful for the summary of the argument if it can be sketched here.

Comment: This is not a constructive comment, but I just find this an entertaining example of something you could put in a novel and (most) readers would not only assume that it was the mathematical equivalent of technobabble but wouldn't believe you if you said it wasn't.

Comment: This is one of the open questions listed at the end of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409567.pdf) by Kechris and Rosendal. Of course, this is a well-known paper which is almost 15 years old, so I wouldn't be surprised if the question is no longer open. But that's some evidence that the proof may not be so easy.

Comment: You might be interested in the [PhD thesis](http://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/17156/1/Siniora_DN_Mathematics_PhD_2017.pdf) of Daoud Siniora. Question 10 at the end of that thesis asks whether there is *any* homogeneous $\omega$-categorical structure with the strict order property which has ample generics.